# Can I use willSet to construct a class instance dictionary entry?

Tags: swift, class, constructor

I am working in xCode 9.2, Swift 4.1

Given these two over simplified classes, which work currently:

```
class Prop : Codable {
    var origin:String?
    var result:String?

    init(_ origin:String) {
        self.origin = origin
    }
}

class PropList : Codable {
    var properties = [String: Prop]()

    func set (property:String, origin:String) {
        if properties[property] == nil {
            properties[property] = Prop(origin) //Create the entry
        } else {
            properties[property]!.origin = origin  //Update the entry
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to use willSet to create an instance of the Prop class for the dictionary entry if it does not already exist?  I tried to code this, but the newValue passed into willSet is actually an entire dictionary.  I suppose this assumes that several entries may be changing at once, which I don't think can actually happen.  Which is why the partial solution below iterates through it.

The reason for wanting to use willSet is so that I can use normal syntax, instead of using a special method call.  With the code above, I call it like this:

```
var pl:PropList = PropList()
pl.set(property: "My Key", origin: "My Origin")
print(pl.properties["My Key"]?.origin as Any)
```

But I would like to be able to do this:

> ```
> var pl2:PropList = PropList()
> pl2.properties["My Key"]?.origin = "My Origin"
> print(pl2.properties["My Key"]?.origin as Any)
> ```
>
> which results in nothing being stored, or:
>
> ```
> var pl2:PropList = PropList()
> pl2.properties["My Key"]!.origin = "My Origin"
> print(pl2.properties["My Key"]?.origin as Any)
> ```
>
> which throws a runtime error.

I was thinking this should work:

```
class PropList {
    var properties = [String: Prop]() {
        willSet {
            for e in newValue {
                if properties[e.key] == nil {
                    properties[e.key] = Prop()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but Swift won't get past not being able to resolve the target before it makes the call.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Checking for `nil` and then force unwrapping is just begging for trouble. Use conditional binding.

Comment: `origin` is optional, but its initialized from an initializer parameter  that is not, all the while being mutable, and without setting `result`? Are you sure this all make sense?

Comment: Alexander - Yes, it is an oversimplification of much more.  The core concept is that it is a dictionary of class instances.  But when one part of an instance is written to, the class instance needs to be constructed, and added to the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can model this nicely with a custom subscript:

```
class Prop: Codable {
    var origin: String?
    var result: String?

    init(_ origin: String) {
        self.origin = origin
    }
}

class PropList: Codable {
    private var properties = [String: Prop]()

    public subscript(_ property: String) -> String? {
        get { return properties[property]?.origin }
        set {
            guard let unwrappedNewValue = newValue else {
                fatalError("Handle me properly!")
            }
            if let existingProperty = properties[property] {
                existingProperty.origin = unwrappedNewValue
                properties[property] = existingProperty
            } else {
                properties[property] = Prop(unwrappedNewValue)
            }
        }
    }
}

var propList = PropList()
propList["Some property"] = "Something called an 'origin' that needs to be better named/documented"
```